# Add "Type to find tags" to my personal tag list

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

If I browse the [tag list in my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474189/duncan?tab=tags), I cannot search for a specific tag. 
I can sort alphabetically, but then I have to guess which page a particular tag would be on. Not easy:

[image: so very many tags]

Can we add the same type of search-as-you-type functionality which is present on the [main site tag page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags)?